# Boostrap card issue on small devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an issue on small devives with the boostrap card. I am using a hover effect to slideup the content.
But on the small devices, the content is cutting the image. I don't really know how to make the content start directly after the image using a position: absolute. I only want to see the name and the title. When mouse hover the rest of the content is showed with a slideup.

```css
.team-card {
border:0!important;
border-radius:5px!important;
overflow:hidden!important;
}

.team-card .card-body .card-title,.team-card .card-body .card-text {
text-align:center;
margin:0;
}

.team-card .card-body {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
left:0;
top:255px;
background-color:#fff;
-moz-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
transition:all .3s ease-in-out
}

.team-card .card-body p {
line-height:1.6em;
}

.team-card:hover .card-body {
top:0;
}

.team-card .card-body .card-text {
margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="card team-card">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190704/ourlarge/pngtree-vector-user-young-boy-avatar-icon-png-image_1538408.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">John Doe</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Business Director</p>
    <p>Board member (core-team) previous Director-Business Development at EM6 and earlier at Syncada.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You see this behavior because you had used an absolute number against `top` property against the classes `.team-card .card-body`; what we could do is assign the following: `top:calc(100% - 89px);` which is the complete height of the `card-body` and we remove 89px which is the height for the `card-title` and `card-text`...

Working **snippet** below:

```css
.team-card {
  border: 0!important;
  border-radius: 5px!important;
  overflow: hidden!important;
}

.team-card .card-body .card-title,
.team-card .card-body .card-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.team-card .card-body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 89px);
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}

.team-card .card-body p {
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

.team-card:hover .card-body {
  top: 0;
}

.team-card .card-body .card-text {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="card team-card">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190704/ourlarge/pngtree-vector-user-young-boy-avatar-icon-png-image_1538408.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">John Doe</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Business Director</p>
    <p>Board member (core-team) previous Director-Business Development at EM6 and earlier at Syncada.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```